# Using the Normalization Condition with Wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction

I'm very confused with this problem and I was looking for some guidance.

$$\psi(x) = Ae^{ikx}e^{-x^2/2a^2}$$
Use the normalization condition to find A.

So I understand that you use the normalization condition where $$\int_\infty^\infty|\psi(x)|^2 dx = 1$$

But the integral is really complicated and doesn't really lead me anywhere. Can anyone suggest a hint? Am I missing something?

$$\int_\infty^\infty (Ae^{ikx}e^{-x^2/2a^2})^2dx$$

$$\int_\infty^\infty (A^2 e^{2ikx}e^{-x^2/a^2})dx$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression $|\psi(x)|^2$ is the complex modulus squared;
$$
  |\psi(x)|^2 = \psi(x)^*\psi(x)
$$
where here the star means complex conjugation.  It follows that for any wavefunction of the form
$$
  \psi(x) = Ae^{ikx} f(x)
$$
where $A$ and $f(x)$ are real, one has
$$
  |\psi(x)|^2 = A^2 f(x)^2
$$
since $|e^{ikx}|^2 = e^{ikx} e^{-ikx} = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that 
$$|\psi|^2 =\psi^*\psi = |A|^2 e^{-x^2/a^2}.$$
We are left with a Gaussian integral.